# anchor css with background - link text squashed into new lines

Tags: css

I am using the following CSS on anchor tags with specific classes.  Works OK except that long link text is forced into new lines.  I guess this has to do with the width...

```
a.interactive {
background:url(../images/icons/icon_interactive.png) left center no-repeat;
padding-left:30px;
height:25px;
width:25px;
display:inline-block;    
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align:text-center;
}
```

Comment: What's your desired outcome? This is extremely vague.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
a.interactive {
background:url(../images/icons/icon_interactive.png) left center no-repeat;
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:inline-block;    
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align:text-center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to maximize the width for that use 100% width or maximum width your design allow you.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.interactive {
    /*...*/
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```